# "For X, use Y" vs. "To represent X, use Y"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, programming

Is it grammatically correct and idiomatic to use "For X, use Y" in the meaning of "To represent X, use Y"? The target document is a programming style guide.

I like the brevity of this construction, but I'm not sure it's a right way to use it.

> - **For** an escaped quotation mark, use `$"`.
> - **For** CR and LF, use `\r` and `\n`.
> - **For** capture groups, use `?<...>`.

> - **To represent** an escaped quotation mark, use `$"`.
> - **To represent** CR and LF, use `\r` and `\n`.
> - ***To create*** capture groups, use `?<...>`.

Comment: 'For' is certainly used as 'in place of': He forced in the nail, using a stone for a hammer'.  And as 'in order to create'. 'For eggs Benedict, poach ....'  But it is very polysemous, and I'd prefer your second set of suggestions.

Comment: The first version can have quite a different meaning than the second version: *For **healthy food** use **organic ingredients**.* You cannot use the alternate phrasing in this case without changing the meaning. If you're going to substitute one for the other, make sure that the substitution is actually appropriate.

Comment: You could use either set. Personally, I prefer the first set. Shorter and just as clear.